# "Failed to chmod" warning in KitKat when trying to openOrCreateDatabase()

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-file

I'm getting this log warn message (on Nexus 4 running stock 4.4):

```
Failed to chmod(/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/mydb.db): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

when calling:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()
```

The message occurs whether the database already exists or not.

The message does not occur when on Galaxy Nexus running stock 4.3.

Why is this happening and is it something that can be safely ignored?

EDIT: I've raised a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64345

Comment: Does the database functionality of your app work after this error?  Generally, the emulated storage is an odd beast, as it's supposed to mimic the no-ownership property of a FAT filesystem, on top of a Unix one.  Two thoughts come to mind: first that this is an attempt to change permission bits on a file when the emulated storage doesn't support that, or second, that the emulated storage is "unexpectedly" supporting file ownership, and you have a stale version of the file left from a previous install of your program under a different UID.

Comment: It would be very interesting to see the output of `adb shell "ls -l /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/mydb.db"`

Comment: Yes, the database works fine after this log message. When I try that command, it becomes clear that the path does not exist. The base path should be "/storage/sdcard0" or "/storage/emulated/legacy". Looks like KitKat is assuming 4.3 emulated storage paths???

Comment: I haven't looked into the details, but it's actually possible that what is mounted and where could be different for the unix user ID ADB runs as, and the user the app runs as.  Does the run-as tool work on your device? (ie, has the bug which recently broke it been fixed?)  If so, you can use that from adb to get a shell as the app user id and then see if the path exists for the app user

Comment: If I try: "run-as com.myapp ls /storage/emulated/" then it lists just one folder "legacy" and no files. So this is the same as if I just ran "ls /storage/emulated" in the adb shell.

Comment: Seems it's not a problem if you are using Context.getExternalFilesDir(null). I'm using a custom directory name under /Android/data instead.

Comment: To correct my earlier thoughts on debugging, it turns out that adb (including run-as) and apps do indeed have a different view of mounts - but it comes not from the unix userid, but rather from the processes's lineage of inheritance.  See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663220/android-getexternalstoragedirectory-returns-invalid-directory/

Comment: Thanks Chris, but unfortunately I don't think this helps with the original question, or am I mistaken?

Comment: It's the explanation of why your investigation was not revealing anything meaningful, but no, it's not a fix.

Comment: I notice the owner of /Android/data/com.myapp is root rather than the u0_aNN of the other packages. Please see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64345 for more details about this. This owner issue is surely related.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue as yours.
It doesn't matter when my app add new table in that database file.
Maybe you can ignore that issue.

Comment: this should be a comment on OP post.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same message too. Just discard it, and your app will keep working fine. You will be able to insert and query your database normally.

Answer (score -1):

I am Taiwanese, I am glad to answer this question.

Yesterday(2014/09/21) I met similar problem (appear same warn message, insert many data from SQL server(10.0.2.2) to 2 tables in emulator SQLite, one table received data, another table is empty).

But Today(2014/09/22) I write another test app. This time I try to insert few data from SQL server(10.0.2.2) into 2 tables of SQLite in SD Card, this time, 2 table received data.

The only difference is `EMULATOR` setting.

**Enlarge SD card space setting, from few MB to 8GB or more if possible.**

Although yellow warning appear once more, but all inserting work success.

[emulator setting photo](http://d.share.photo.xuite.net/hung2075/1d21feb/19171198/1050089069_l.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, but this question is about the log messages, not the insertion success.  The insertion was always working fine.  Furthermore, my tests were carried out on a real device with >1GB available space, so I don't think thst is an issue here either.

Comment: An answer ending with 'Yellow warning appear once more' isn't a correct one. Still looking for the reason of this warning.