# Android getExternalStorageDirectory() returns invalid directory

Tags: android

I am trying to add OBB file support and I have run into a bizare situation. When I call `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, it returns a path that does not exist on my device.

I call this at the start of my app:

```
Log.i( LOG_ID, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX <--- "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() );
```

It returns:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX <--- /storage/emulated/0
```

But when I connect via `adb -d shell` and run `ls -al /storage/emulated` I get:

```
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2013-12-04 15:17 legacy -> /mnt/shell/emulated/0
```

As you can see the path `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returned is not valid on my device. Any idea why this would be and how I can locate the OBB files without hard coding `/mnt/sdcard/`?

EDIT:

I have just run some further testing:

```
Works - stat( "/sdcard/Android/obb" );
Fails - stat( "/sdcard/Android/obb/uk.co.mycomp.myapp" );

shell@android:/mnt/shell $ ls -ald /sdcard/Android/obb/                        
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2013-12-18 16:42 
shell@android:/mnt/shell $ ls -ald  /sdcard/Android/obb/uk.co.mycomp.myapp
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2013-12-18 18:36
```

As you can see the two directories are identical yet I can only access the parent. This may or may not have any relevance to my issue...

Comment: have you declared the required permission on your manifest?

Comment: Have you actually tried using the code to access files? Or are you just assuming it doesn't work

Comment: I think I have the right permissions, but to be clear which should I be looking for?

Comment: Yes I have tried accessing the files and I got a file not found error which is how I became aware of the issue...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>In recent Android versions, the mounts are actually different for different user ID's, which invalidates the way you are trying to investigate this.</strike>

Your attempt at investigating the storage paths is frustrated by the fact that recent Android versions leverage the "Per-process namespaces" feature of the Linux kernel to provide different sets of mounts to different process ancestries.  This is likely connected to the efforts towards supporting multiple (human) user accounts, with both unique and shared sub-sections of External Storage.

When you run an adb shell, you get a set of mounts inherited from adbd.

But in contrast, code run by an application (either in it's process, or a child process) gets a *different* set of mounts, apparently either inherited from zygote or configured soon thereafter by the process differentiation code which turns a freshly budded zygote into your app's process.

To get an idea of what mounts your app sees, install something like `connectbot` which you can use to get a local shell descended from an application process, and run the mount command, or any other investigation of interest.  For example:

```
u0_a99@build:/ $ mount

/dev/fuse /storage/emulated/0 fuse rw....
/dev/fuse /storage/emulated/legacy fuse rw.....
```

In comparison, checking from the adb shell:

```
shell@build:/mnt $ mount

/dev/fuse /mnt/shell/emulated fuse rw.....
```

---

**Confusingly**, because the mounts are determined by the processes's *ancestry* rather than it's *user id*, using the `run-as` tool from adb **will not** get you the same view as an application process or it's child, but rather instead will give you adb's view.

However, if you have the pid of a running app's process, you can use run-as to look in it's `/proc/pid##/mounts` file, without having to actually get a shell descended from the app.

Comment: That explains perfectly what is happening and having installed a shell app I can see that the path does exist in the app space. However my edit above about accessing the OBB sub directory still remains. Is this in any way related?

Comment: Turns out its the same issue. `adb -d push` sees the same mount space as the shell, which is not the same as the app. So the OBB push was uploading to the wrong location. Thanks for your help...

Comment: Yes, I'd expect you would get the same mounts for all adb commands.  I hadn't realized you were trying to simulate the OBB.